# Shiny leaflet rendering twice on input

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, reactive, shiny-server

I'm having a glitch in my shiny leaflet map I'm hoping to get some help with.

This map is built to show distributions of different species in two different sampling years. In the app, you can select the species and sample year to view, and if desired, you can select a custom threshold to view on the map (e.g. only color squares with between 50-200 frogs).

The map works well, mostly. The issue I'm having is that the custom threshold input builds a color palette based on a renderUI input (slider values), and if you try to switch species WHILE "custom threshold" is selected, you get a glitch. Basically what's happening is the app tries to build a color palette for the OLD species first and projects the raster map that way, then updates really quickly to the new species.

What this means in practice is that if you have "custom threshold" turned on, and you move from projecting distributions of frogs (with lower limits) to toads, the map renders first with the old frog threshold values, before quickly re-rendering with the updated (toad) input values. When you go the other way, from toad (higher limit species) to frog, the app crashes, because the palette tries to build with the old, higher limits (from toads numbers), which exceed the possible values for frogs. The specific line is the construction of a palette using a "times" argument. It's noted in the code below.

Thank you!

```
options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none") # mute warnings from rgdal because I'm using proj strings
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(leaflet)
library(raster)


set.seed(1)
frog <- data.frame(x=sample(seq(from=-105, to=-95,by=.4), 300, replace = T),
                   y = sample(seq(from=35, to=45,by=.4), 300, replace=T),
                   sample1 = runif(300,min=10, max = 230),
                   sample2 = runif(300,min=10, max = 230))
toad <- data.frame(x=sample(seq(from=-105, to=-95,by=.4), 500, replace = T),
                   y = sample(seq(from=35, to=45,by=.4), 500, replace=T),
                   sample1 = runif(500,min=100, max = 900),
                   sample2 = runif(500,min=100, max = 900))


# Define UI for application that draws a map of species occurrences
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Finding Frogs and Toads"),

    # Sidebar with a selections for species, sample number, and custom thresholds
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            
            # Widget specifying the species to be included on the plot - starts on Frog
            radioGroupButtons(
                inputId = "species",
                label = "Target Species",
                choiceNames  = list("Frog", 
                                    "Toad"),
                choiceValues = list("frog","toad"),
                selected = "frog",
                justified = TRUE,
                status= "primary"
            ),
            
            # Widget specifying the sample to be displayed
            selectInput("sample",
                        "Select sample",
                        choices  = list("1" = "1",
                                        "2" = "2"),
                        selected = "1",
            ),
            
            # button to specify custom input y/n
            switchInput(
                inputId = "custom",
                label = "Custom Threshold", 
                labelWidth = "100%"
            ),
            
            # ui unpit to set custom thresholds to show in plot
            uiOutput("reactive_slider")
            
        ),
        

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            column(width = 12,
                   # Leaflet map
                   leafletOutput('map', height = "90vh"),
                   
            ),
        )
    )
)



# Define server logic ---------------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # set limits for scales, dependent on species
    spp_lim <- reactive({
        switch(input$species,
               "frog" = c(0:250), # highest frog density is 250
               "toad" = c(0:1000), # highest toad density is 1000
        )
    })
    
    # make start values for the reactive slider 
    slider_startvals <- reactiveValues(start = c(NA,NA))
  
    observe({
      if(input$species=="frog"){
        slider_startvals$start <- c(20,160)
      }
      if(input$species=="toad"){
        slider_startvals$start <- c(150,500)
      }
    })
    
    
    # make the reactive slider to choose thresholds to view
    output$reactive_slider <- renderUI(
        sliderInput("reactive_slider", label = "Slider Range", 
                    min = 0, 
                    max = max(spp_lim()), # total scale limits dependent on species
                    value = slider_startvals$start # set sliders to start values above
        )
    ) # end output reactive_slider

    
    
    # create palette for map, based either on species limits, or on manual input from slider
    map_pal <- reactiveValues()
    
    observe({
      # if custom threshoild limit button is not selected, show with Viridis scale
      if (input$custom == "FALSE"){
        map_pal$pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "plasma", 
                                    spp_lim(),
                                    na.color = "transparent",
                                    reverse=F)
        
      } else{ 
        # if custom thresholds limit is selected, build a palette of grey / purple / grey using custom slider inputs
        
        # NOTE: these "times" arguments are the problem piece! 
        # when species is changed, the palette tries to build with the OLD slider values,
        # which don't exist because they are out of range when moving from toad to frog,
        # or are too low when moving frog to toad. 
        map_pal$pal <-  colorNumeric(palette = c(rep(c("grey70"), times = input$reactive_slider[1]),
                                                 rep(c("purple"), times = (input$reactive_slider[2]-input$reactive_slider[1])),
                                                 rep(c("grey70"), times = (max(spp_lim())-input$reactive_slider[2]))  ), 
                                     domain = spp_lim(),
                                     na.color="transparent",
                                     reverse=F)
      }
    })
    
    
    # make a reverse palette for legend - same as above, but in reverse
    map_pal_rev <- reactiveValues()
    
    observe({
      
      if (input$custom == "FALSE"){
        map_pal_rev$pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "plasma", 
                                        spp_lim(),
                                        na.color = "transparent",
                                        reverse=T)
        
      } else{ # then with set thresholds
        
        # again, the "times" argument is the problematic piece, see above. 
        map_pal_rev$pal <-  colorNumeric(palette = c(rep(c("grey70"), times = input$reactive_slider[1]),
                                                 rep(c("purple"), times = (input$reactive_slider[2]-input$reactive_slider[1])),
                                                 rep(c("grey70"), times = (max(spp_lim())-input$reactive_slider[2]))  ), 
                                     domain = spp_lim(),
                                     na.color="transparent",
                                     reverse=T)
        
      }
    })
    
  
    # make reactive data from input species dataset and sample number
    map_dat <- reactive({
      get(input$species) %>%  
        dplyr::select(x,y,paste0("sample",input$sample))
    })
    
    # rasterize map data object
    map_dat_raster <- reactive({
      rasterFromXYZ(map_dat(), 
                    crs = "+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 ")
      
   })
    
    
    # make blank map
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      
      leaflet('map', options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 3, maxZoom = 7, zoomControl = TRUE)) %>%
        addProviderTiles("CartoDB.VoyagerNoLabels") %>%
        setView(lng = -100, lat = 46, zoom = 4) 
      
    }) # end render map
    
    
    # add proxy for showing raster object
    observe({
      
      pal <-   map_pal$pal
      dfr <- map_dat_raster()
      
      leafletProxy("map") %>%
        clearImages() %>%
        addRasterImage(dfr, colors = pal, opacity = 0.7,
                       project=TRUE)
    })
    
    # add proxy for legend opject
    observe({
      
      pal <- map_pal_rev$pal # this uses the reverse palette because I want it high-to-low
      leafletProxy("map") %>%
        clearControls() %>%
        addLegend(position = "bottomright",
                  pal = pal, 
                  values = spp_lim(),
                  title = paste0(stringr::str_to_title(input$species)," density (kg/km2)"),
                  opacity = 1,
                  labFormat = labelFormat(transform = function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)
                  )
                  
        )
    })
    
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

A work around for the lazy evaluation is shown below

```
options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none") # mute warnings from rgdal because I'm using proj strings
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(leaflet)
library(raster)


set.seed(1)
frog <- data.frame(x=sample(seq(from=-105, to=-95,by=.4), 300, replace = T),
                   y = sample(seq(from=35, to=45,by=.4), 300, replace=T),
                   sample1 = runif(300,min=10, max = 230),
                   sample2 = runif(300,min=10, max = 230))
toad <- data.frame(x=sample(seq(from=-105, to=-95,by=.4), 500, replace = T),
                   y = sample(seq(from=35, to=45,by=.4), 500, replace=T),
                   sample1 = runif(500,min=100, max = 900),
                   sample2 = runif(500,min=100, max = 900))


# Define UI for application that draws a map of species occurrences
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Finding Frogs and Toads"),
  
  # Sidebar with a selections for species, sample number, and custom thresholds
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Widget specifying the species to be included on the plot - starts on Frog
      radioGroupButtons(
        inputId = "species",
        label = "Target Species",
        choiceNames  = list("Frog", 
                            "Toad"),
        choiceValues = list("frog","toad"),
        selected = "frog",
        justified = TRUE,
        status= "primary"
      ),
      
      # Widget specifying the sample to be displayed
      selectInput("sample",
                  "Select sample",
                  choices  = list("1" = "1",
                                  "2" = "2"),
                  selected = "1",
      ),
      
      # button to specify custom input y/n
      switchInput(
        inputId = "custom",
        label = "Custom Threshold", 
        labelWidth = "100%"
      ),
      
      # ui unpit to set custom thresholds to show in plot
      uiOutput("reactive_slider")
      
    ),
    
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel( # verbatimTextOutput("t1"),
      column(width = 12,
             # Leaflet map
             leafletOutput('map', height = "90vh"),
             
      ),
    )
  )
)



# Define server logic ---------------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # set limits for scales, dependent on species
  spp_lim <- eventReactive(input$species, {
    switch(input$species,
           "frog" = c(0:250), # highest frog density is 250
           "toad" = c(0:1000), # highest toad density is 1000
    )
  })
  
  # make start values for the reactive slider 
  slider_startvals <- reactiveValues(start = c(NA,NA))
  
  observeEvent(input$species, {
    if(input$species=="frog"){
      slider_startvals$start <- c(20,160)
    }
    if(input$species=="toad"){
      slider_startvals$start <- c(150,500)
    }
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE )
  
  
  # make the reactive slider to choose thresholds to view
  output$reactive_slider <- renderUI({
    req(spp_lim(),input$species)
    sliderInput("reactive_slider", label = "Slider Range", 
                min = 0, 
                max = max(spp_lim()), # total scale limits dependent on species
                value = slider_startvals$start # set sliders to start values above
    )
  }) # end output reactive_slider
  
  
  
  # create palette for map, based either on species limits, or on manual input from slider
  map_pal <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    
    # if custom threshoild limit button is not selected, show with Viridis scale
    if (!input$custom){
      map_pal$pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "plasma", 
                                  spp_lim(),
                                  na.color = "transparent",
                                  reverse=F)
      
    } else{ 
      # if custom thresholds limit is selected, build a palette of grey / purple / grey using custom slider inputs
      
      # NOTE: these "times" arguments are the problem piece! 
      # when species is changed, the palette tries to build with the OLD slider values,
      # which don't exist because they are out of range when moving from toad to frog,
      # or are too low when moving frog to toad. 
      req(input$reactive_slider[1],input$reactive_slider[2],spp_lim())
      mytimes <- ifelse(max(spp_lim())>input$reactive_slider[2] , max(spp_lim())-input$reactive_slider[2], input$reactive_slider[2])
      map_pal$pal <-  colorNumeric(palette = c(rep(c("grey70"), times = input$reactive_slider[1]),
                                               rep(c("purple"), times = (input$reactive_slider[2]-input$reactive_slider[1])),
                                               rep(c("grey70"), times = mytimes) ), 
                                   domain = spp_lim(),
                                   na.color="transparent",
                                   reverse=F)
                                   
    }
  })
  
  output$t1 <- renderPrint({paste(input$reactive_slider[1], input$reactive_slider[2], max(spp_lim()), mytimes )})
  
  # make a reverse palette for legend - same as above, but in reverse
  map_pal_rev <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    
    if (!input$custom){
      map_pal_rev$pal2 <- colorNumeric(palette = "plasma", 
                                      spp_lim(),
                                      na.color = "transparent",
                                      reverse=T)
      
    } else{ # then with set thresholds
      req(input$reactive_slider[1],input$reactive_slider[2],spp_lim())
      # again, the "times" argument is the problematic piece, see above. 
      mytimes2 <- ifelse(max(spp_lim())>input$reactive_slider[2] , max(spp_lim())-input$reactive_slider[2], input$reactive_slider[2])
      map_pal_rev$pal2 <-  colorNumeric(palette = c(rep(c("grey70"), times = input$reactive_slider[1]),
                                                   rep(c("purple"), times = (input$reactive_slider[2]-input$reactive_slider[1])),
                                                   rep(c("grey70"), times = mytimes2 )  ), 
                                       domain = spp_lim(),
                                       na.color="transparent",
                                       reverse=T)
      
    }
  })
  
  
  # make reactive data from input species dataset and sample number
  map_dat <- reactive({
    req(input$species,input$sample)
    get(input$species) %>%  
      dplyr::select(x,y,paste0("sample",input$sample))
  })
  
  # rasterize map data object
  map_dat_raster <- reactive({
    req(map_dat())
    rasterFromXYZ(map_dat(), 
                  crs = "+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 ")
    
  })
  
  
  # make blank map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    
    leaflet('map', options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 3, maxZoom = 7, zoomControl = TRUE)) %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.VoyagerNoLabels") %>%
      setView(lng = -100, lat = 46, zoom = 4) 
    
  }) # end render map
  
  
  # add proxy for showing raster object
  observe({
    
    pal <- map_pal$pal  
    dfr <- map_dat_raster()
    
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearImages() %>%
      addRasterImage(dfr, colors = pal, opacity = 0.7,
                     project=TRUE)
  })
  
  # add proxy for legend opject
  observe({
    
    pal <- map_pal_rev$pal2 # this uses the reverse palette because I want it high-to-low
    leafletProxy("map") %>%
      clearControls() %>%
      addLegend(position = "bottomright",
                pal = pal, 
                values = spp_lim(),
                title = paste0(stringr::str_to_title(input$species)," density (kg/km2)"),
                opacity = 1,
                labFormat = labelFormat(transform = function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)
                )
                
      )
  })
  
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```